# Json Data in int format

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsinteger

I am parsing json and the url is returning an integer value. (e.g. 278)

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON Response = %@",responseString);}
```

when I am printing response in NSLog, it gives out something like this

`2012-09-15 18:02:02.091 Web Service[5190:f803] JSON Response = "278"`

I don't want the output in quotes. I want it like

`2012-09-15 18:02:02.091 Web Service[5190:f803] JSON Response = 278`

how can i achieve this?

JSON

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.5.6.105/ARAPPWS/Service1/InsertEmp/name=%@,phone=%@",name.text,number.text];
    NSURL *addUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; 
    NSURLRequest *addRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:addUrl];
    (void)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:addRequest delegate:self];

-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
jsonData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];


}
-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[jsonData appendData:data];

}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection
{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[self performSelector:@selector(uploadEmpImg:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `- [NSString integerValue]` to obtain the actual numerical representation of the string:

```
NSLog(@"JSON response = %d", [responseString integerValue]);
```

Edit: the problem is that it returns a JSON fragment - strictly speaking it's not valid JSON. You can then use

```
[responseString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, responseString.length - 2)]
```

to get the actual string value without the quotes and

```
[[responseString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, responseString.length - 2)] intValue]
```

to get it as an integer.

Comment: it is giving me JSON Response = 0 instead of JSON Response = 278

Comment: @Ankur so does the webservice return `278` or `"278"`? By the way, why don't you use a proper JSON parser instead of hacking?

Comment: my web service return 278.
I am new to JSON parsing I don't know how to use proper JSON.

Comment: @Ankur I mean the JSON the service responds with. I'm not interested in the Objective-C part.

Comment: please check this link 
http://rootinfosolutions.org/arappws/service1/help
 3rd service in this .
I am sorry other than that I don't have anything. this is written by one of my colleague